# Map predictions back to IDs - Python Scikit Learn DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree, valueerror

I have a dataset that has a unique identifier and other features. It looks like this

> ```
> ID      LenA TypeA LenB TypeB Diff Score Response
> 123-456  51   M     101  L     50   0.2   0
> 234-567  46   S     49   S     3    0.9   1
> 345-678  87   M     70   M     17   0.7   0
> ```

I split it up into training and test data. I am trying to classify test data into two classes from a classifier trained on training data. I want the identifier in the training and testing dataset so I can **map the predictions back to the IDs**.
 Is there a way that I can assign the identifier column as a ID or non-predictor like we can do in Azure ML Studio or SAS?

I am using the `DecisionTreeClassifier` from Scikit-Learn. This is the code I have for the classifier.

```
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(traindata, trainlabels)
```

If I just include the ID into the `traindata`, the code throws an error:

> `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 123-456`

Comment: How are you making your train/test split?

Comment: @Grr .. For now, I'm just splitting it in half and loading the CSVs separately as traindata and testdata.

Answer (score 6):

Not knowing how you made your split I would suggest just making sure the `ID` column is not included in your training data. Something like this perhaps:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = test_train_split(df.ix[:, ~df.columns.isin(['ID', 'Response'])].values, df.Response)
```

That will split only the values from the DataFrame not in `ID` or `Response` for the `X` values, and split `Response` for the `y` values.

But you will still not be able to use the `DecisionTreeClassifier` with this data as it contains strings. You will need to convert any column with categorical data, i.e. `TypeA` and `TypeB` to a numerical representation. The best way to do this in my opinion for sklearn is with the [`LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). Using this will convert the categorical string labels `['M', 'S']` into `[1, 2]` which can be implemented with the `DecisionTreeClassifier`.  If you need an example take a look at [Passing categorical data to sklearn decision tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108832/passing-categorical-data-to-sklearn-decision-tree).

**Update**

Per your comment I now understand that you need to map back to the `ID`. In this case you can leverage pandas to your advantage. Set `ID` as the index of your data and then do the split, that way you will retain the `ID` value for all of your train and test data. Let's assume your data are already in a pandas dataframe.

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = test_train_split(df.ix[:, ~df.columns.isin(['Response'])], df.Response)
print(X_train)
         LenA TypeA  LenB TypeB  Diff  Score
ID
345-678    87     M    70     M    17    0.7
234-567    46     S    49     S     3    0.9
```

Comment: How is that going to help me map the predictions to the ID? If I split the data using the trian_test_split function using the above code, I still won't have ID in the dataset, will I?

Comment: Lets say I run `clf.predict(X_test)` here, are my results going to have the same index as X_test? If so, I can merge the results dataframe and X_test dataframe on index, right?

Comment: @Minu They will not share the exact index. For example the index of X_test in my example will be `Index(['345-678'], dtype='object', name='ID')` where as the results of `predict` will not have an explicit index. However, the order will still be the same so you could "join" them, just not with then `pandas.DataFrame.join` method. Something like this would work: `X_test['predicted'] = results`

Comment: In that case, there's no necessity to set the IDs as index, correct? I can concat the X_test data and predicted results based on the order of the rows even without index being IDs.

Comment: Also, when I try to OneHotEncode with index = ID, I get an error: `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: You did not understand the question. The question about how to join prediction back into id, not split data set with id. (ex some use-case: to submit to kaggle, your submission is a pair of id-prediction)

Answer (score 0):

The pandas dataframe keep its order when you do transformation (except join/merge that create/drop row).

So, Here is step-by-step:

1. create `df_test` dataframe with 'id' column
2. create `df_test2` that don't have 'id' column
   `df_test2 = df_test.drop(["id"], axis=1)`
3. Input `df_test2` into model for prediction `pred = model.predict(df_test2)`
4. create `df_pred_final` from 'id' column from df_test `df_pred_final = df_test[["id"]]`
5. add column 'target' into `df_pred_final`. The pair id-target should be map correctly `df_pred_final["target"] = pred`

Please take a look at my kaggle notebook. You might get the idea.
https://www.kaggle.com/tthien/20210412-complex-drop-c10-c2