# Training model with ID column

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, apache-spark-ml

I am working on training a model with scikit-learn where I have an ID column in my dataset. I remove the ID column when I train the model.But with the test dataset,I need to map it back to the ID column after I do the prediction.

What is the best way to do this? We can set a non predictor column when building a model in scikit-learn? Also, what about the other ML tools like TensorFlow,Spark ML in general. Do they support this feature?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43549034/map-predictions-back-to-ids-python-scikit-learn-decisiontreeclassifier) on stackoverflow but was looking out for other options.

Comment: Just dont send the ID column while predicting. The output will match the input.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you store your data (X) in a pd.DataFrame.
If that is the case, simply extract the values into a numpy ndarray. The corresponding rows will have the same order. A scikit-learn stylized example:

```
output = pd.Series(data=some_model.predict(X.values), index=X.index)
```

Comment: And which algo will let us run `.predict()` on an X matrix wider by 1 column than X used for training? Or did we train on the ID column as well?