# Multiclass MultiOutput Classification with both categorical and continous attribute without encoding in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I'm Working on a Machine learning (Data-Mining) project and i'm done with data exploration and data preparation step and it was done in python!

Now I'm facing this issue : i have categoricals attributes in my dataset .
After research i've found that the best appropriate algorithm for that kind of data is a decision tree or a random forrest classifier !

But I've read some similar questions about decision tree and categorical attribute and found that the library I'm using (scikit-learn) doesn't works with categoricasl attributes . check [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108832/passing-categorical-data-to-sklearn-decision-tree) , for making it work with categorical i need to encode my categorical variables into numerical ones but i don't want to use encoding because i will loose some properties of my attributes and some informations according to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5229/30464) answer , and also some of my attributes has more than 100 different values.

So I want to know :

- is there any other python library that can build decision trees with categorical data without any encoding?
- in [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5229/30464) answer it was suggest that other libraries like WEKA can build decisions trees with categorical attributes so my question is this can I combine 2 language in the same machine learning project?

Will do data exploration and preparation in python, train the model in weka (java), and deploy it in a python-flask web app?
can it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/5229/30464) you linked about encoding categorical inputs is just saying that you should avoid numerical encoding when your categories don't have an inherent order. It correctly recommends that you use a one-hot encoding in this case.

Simply put, machine learning models operate on numbers, so even if you find a library that takes your raw categories without explicit encoding, it will still have to internally encode them before it can perform any computation.

100 categories is not a lot, and most of the shelf libraries will handle such inputs just fine. I recommend you try [xgboost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html)

Comment: ok! Thanks for your response @Imran  so i will try one hot encoding sound good but will increase the dimension of my dataset , so have to forget about decision tree and try strong classifier like SVN and NN .