# In sklearn, how can one-hot encoding help when building decision tree with categorical features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

According to [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest), sklearn can not handle categorical variables. And use one-hot encoding to deal with these features are suggested. However, I do not understand how can one-hot encoding help? For example, country=USA or China or England is transformed into country=USA is true or false, the new feature 'country==USA' is still categorical after all (can only take 0 or 1). That does not change anything. Sklearn still treats 0 or 1 as numerical values.

For a real example [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/arundhaj/datamining_class/blob/master/decision_tree.ipynb), I transformed data:

```
human,warm-blooded,hair,yes,no,no,yes,no,mammal
python,cold-blooded,scales,no,no,no,no,yes,reptile
salmon,cold-blooded,scales,no,yes,no,no,no,fish
whale,warm-blooded,hair,yes,yes,no,no,no,mammal
frog,cold-blooded,none,no,semi,no,yes,yes,amphibian
komodo dragon,cold-blooded,scales,no,no,no,yes,no,reptile
bat,warm-blooded,hair,yes,no,yes,yes,yes,mammal
pigeon,warm-blooded,feathers,no,no,yes,yes,no,bird
cat,warm-blooded,fur,yes,no,no,yes,no,mammal
leopard shark,cold-blooded,scales,yes,yes,no,no,no,fish
turtle,cold-blooded,scales,no,semi,no,yes,no,reptile
penguin,warm-blooded,feathers,no,semi,no,yes,no,bird
porcupine,warm-blooded,quills,yes,no,no,yes,yes,mammal
eel,cold-blooded,scales,no,yes,no,no,no,fish
salamander,cold-blooded,none,no,semi,no,yes,yes,amphibian
gila monster,cold-blooded,scales,no,no,no,yes,yes,
```

into

```
[[1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

and build a decision tree like

[decision tree(click to open)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQnsI.png)
The split point is still ridiculous(like Give Birth=no<=0.5). So I do not think one-hot encoding can help deal with categorical data at all.

Comment: What they probably mean is that sklearn cannot handle features with multiple categories.  sklearn converts everything to floats, so 1s and 0s are fine, but something like a 3 label class (data ∈ {0,1,2}) will have an implicit order.  I think you're fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we must also keep in mind  that SKlearn can [only build binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586562/scikit-decision-tree-categorical-features). For example, there is a color feature which takes 0,1,2,3,4,5 for different colors. We split the color feature using color<=2.5, then 0,1,2 is the left leaf, 3,4,5 is the right leaf, which is not what we desired as there is no order in features. If there is indeed an order, I think we can do without one-hot encoding.

The one-hot encoding can act as if Sklearn can handle categorical data. For example, if there is a real feature "country==USA" in the data which takes 0 or 1 and it is used as the splitting feature, then the leaves are country==USA is 0 and country==USA is 1. Although Sklearn still uses numerical splitting points such as 0.5 (the splitting point must between 0 and 1 or it won't be a good split), if country==USA<=0.5  goes to the left leaf, else goes to the right leaf, 'country==USA is 0' will go to the left leaf and 'country==USA is 1' will go to the right one, which is the same effect of splitting the "country==USA" feature according to 0 and 1.