# Does integer encoding of strings and using this as an input to decision tree (sklearn) makes the splitting attributes discrete or continuous?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have to use Decision Tree classifier to classify certain data. However, the attribute values are strings, and as I found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/strings-as-features-in-decision-tree-random-forest), it said that strings cannot be used as an input. Hence I used integer encoding for the strings.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108832/passing-categorical-data-to-sklearn-decision-tree) article, I found out that passing integer-encoded data may result in a wrong answer since sklearn assumes an ordering among the data. So, the only way out is using `OneHotEncoder` module.

Using `OneHotEncoder` module increases the number of features (e.g. if there is an attribute 'price' with values `['high','med','low']`, one-hot-encoding would result in inclusion of 3 attributes related to the actual attribute 'price'; those can be interpreted as `['price-high','price-med', 'price-low']` and the attribute values will be either 1 or 0 depending on the data), which I don't want since I have to print the decision tree in a certain format which would require the original features (e.g. I need 'price').

Is there a way out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) would be useful since you want to keep track of the original feature names, when creating one-hot vectors.

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price': ['high', 'medium', 'high', 'low'], 'some_feature': ['b', 'a', 'c','a']})
pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['price','some_feature'])

    price_high  price_low   price_medium    some_feature_a  some_feature_b  some_feature_c
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1   1   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   1
3   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

When feed this dataframe to decision tree, you could get a better understanding!

Comment: Sure. That would convert the data to one-hot-encoded form. But, the Decision Tree will be constructed on the new features (e.g. price_high, price_low, etc). So while printing the Decision Tree, the features would not be "price" or "some_feature", but "price_high", "price_low", etc.

Comment: yes. why do you want the see just the `price` as feature name when we already created dummies for it. I think, having it as `price_high` would have more explanation of how the split has been made in the decision tree