# sklearn decision tree - could not convert string to float

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a CSV file containing car information from truecar.com and I want to predict the price of a car with this data but I get an error. here is the traceback :

```
File "x\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'exterior_color'
```

code :

```
import csv
from sklearn import tree

x = [] 
y = [] 

with open('x', 'r') as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in data:
        x.append(line[0:-2])
        y.append(line[-1])

    # print(x)
    # print(y)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DecisionTreeClassifier`'s `fit` method takes arrays of float in it's `X` parameter[(documentation)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit).

I would suggest you to one hot encode your non-numeric variables. I would suggest you reading some articles about this methodology that transforms a column of categorical data into multiple columns of boolean values.

[Passing categorical data to Sklearn Decision Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108832/passing-categorical-data-to-sklearn-decision-tree)

[Why One-Hot Encode Data in Machine Learning?](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)